# MySQL select only rows with max datetime grouped by foreign

Tags: mysql

I'm implementing a forum system and I have these tables:

- `forums` : **`id`**, `title`, `created_at`
- `forum_topics` : `id`, `title`, **`forum_id`** `created_at`
- `forum_replies` : `id`, `content`, **`forum_topic_id`** **`created_at`**

I'm trying to get all the forums but I want to add also the last created forum_reply.

I'm really stuck in this. Any help please

For example:

I have 3 forums:

- 1, forum1
- 2, forum2
- 3, forum3

and this topics (id, title, forum_id):

- 1, topic1_forum1, 1
- 2, topic1_forum2, 2
- 3, topic2_forum2, 2
- 4, topic1_forum3, 3
- 5, topic2_forum3, 3

finally, this replies (id, content, forum_topic_id, created_at)

- 1, content, 1, 2015-01-01 00:00:00
- 2, content, 1, 2015-02-01 20:00:00
- 3, content, 2, 2015-02-01 22:00:00
- 4, content, 2, 2015-02-01 22:30:00
- 5, content, 3, 2015-01-01 00:00:00
- 6, content, 4, 2015-01-01 00:00:00
- 7, content, 5, 2015-01-02 20:00:00
- 8, content, 5, 2015-01-03 00:00:00

So my final result should look like this:

(forums.id, forum.title, forum_topics.id, forum_topics.title, forum_replies.id, forum_replies.content, forum_replies.timestamp)

- 1, forum1, 1, topic1_forum1, 2, content, 2015-02-01 20:00:00
- 2, forum2, 2, topic1_forum2, 4, content, 2015-02-01 22:30:00
- 3, forum3, 5, topic2_forum3, 8, content, 2015-01-03 00:00:00

### EDIT

[SQLFiddle full with tables and data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f986a)

Comment: Please elaborate on the result set you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps to this process - the first is identifying the most recent post.  The second is to retrieve the rest of the information (such as the topic title and reply content) which requires joining to that result set again.

```
select *
from forums f 
  left join forum_topics ft
    on f.id = ft.forum_id
  left join forum_replies fp
    on ft.id = fp.forum_topic_id
  left join (
    SELECT f.id, MAX(fp.created_at) created_at
      FROM forums f 
        INNER JOIN forum_topics ft
          ON f.id = ft.forum_id
        INNER JOIN forum_replies fp
          ON ft.id = fp.forum_topic_id
      GROUP BY f.id
  ) q
    on fp.created_at = q.created_at
      and f.id = q.id
    where fp.created_at = q.created_at
      or fp.id is null;
```

Comment: I don't think we need the `fp.created_at = q.created_at` condition since table `q` should only have unique `id` value after the `GROUP BY` (by the way I upvoted you).

Comment: It is needed, f.id is repeated in the outer query, so each row would join to the inner query if there was only the one predicate

Comment: This solves my problem. Thanks. I just got one more question. This only returns the forums which actually got topics. How can I get the forums that doesn't?? I guess I have to switch an `inner join` with a `left join` but I didn't get which one(s). Thanks!

Comment: I tried that, but comes up with lots of duplicated data. :/

Comment: if you duplicate your question with sample data at sqfiddle.com, i'll have a crack.  the way you've presented the data in the question makes it laborious to copy there, and i'm lazy :)

Comment: Seems like the site is down but I solved changing all the `inner joins` with `left joins` and grouping by `f.id`.

Comment: that won't always work - i promise. maybe update your question with create and insert statements that i can work with?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. sqlfiddle returned. I'll update my question.

Comment: It would also be great to ignore deleted data (deleted_at not null)